# Issues with the git module installation

Tags: python, git

I have tried to install git with both pip/pip3 and conda.
When doing with pip/pip3 i get the following in shell:

```
(base) Micheles-MacBook-Air:~ michelegiglioni$ pip install git
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions:none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for git

(base) Micheles-MacBook-Air:~ michelegiglioni$ pip3 install git
Collecting git
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for git
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
```

I have also updated git to the latest version and re-run the pip install command with no success.
I have also tried going through with conda with the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge git
```

It apparently downloaded git but then the result in JupiterLab is still the following:

```
import git

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-99021728f681> in <module>
----> 1 import git

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'git'
```

Do you have any suggestions on how i could proceed to use the git module?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no git package in the PyPI official site allowing you to execute the command `pip install git`. That's why your first command is failing. Probably you're trying with the wrong package name.

If [this](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#installing-gitpython) is the package you're looking for, try the command `pip install gitpython`.